# How to average spending at a specific location by week on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, to start I am looking to average the amount of money spent at a specific store each week using excel. Headers are as follows: C = Debit, F = Date, and G = Description.

I am trying to set up a formula that will only select rows whose Description (G) matches "*HOLIDAY*", average Debit (C) expenses by one-week intervals, and from there average every week. Pretty much just trying to find out how much is spent at one particular store each week on average.

I tried using the Averageifs statement to incorporate only the specific holiday stores I was looking for =AVERAGEIFS(G:G,"*HOLIDAY STATION*",C:C). This just returned the average spent at Holiday, but I'm looking to get average spent weekly at holiday. However, I do not know how to separate dates into one-week intervals as they are stored in date form (Ex. 3/23/2023). Please help me:)

Comment: Please provide a sample in [Table Markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) and the expected output. Thanks

Comment: Holiday station or holiday? I guess its arbitrary - I've assumed Holiday-  see below (up/down vote as you deem fit for the benefit of future individuals with similar query) ta

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C:C, G:G, "HOLIDAY", F:F, "<=" & SEQUENCE(20,1,TODAY()+7,7), F:F, ">" & SEQUENCE(20,1,TODAY(),7) ),"n/a")
```

[image: direct answer]

- This requires Office 365 Excel compatibility.
- It will give you an array of average debits, where the averaging 'window' corresponds to weekly increments, commencing 'today()' (20 such increments have been used).  It also filters out non-holidays (returning the average debit corresponding to hols)
- Customize the starting date & number of weeks as req.

*(best practice is to restrict the ranges to the dimensions of the sample data in question - albeit laziness on my part has resulted in referencing entire cols, e.g. C:C etc)*

---

```
=LET(y_,SEQUENCE(20,1,TODAY(),7),x_,IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C:C, G:G, "HOLIDAY", F:F, "<=" & SEQUENCE(20,1,TODAY()+7,7), F:F, ">" & SEQUENCE(20,1,TODAY(),7) ),"n/a"),HSTACK(y_,x_))
```

[image: bells/whistles]

Take this one step further, here is a modified version of the above function that returns a matrix comprising two columns: the first will have the dates in question; the second is simply the result of the first equation above.

---

other notes/disclaimers:

- (weeks unaccounted for/for which there is no 'debit' data return as 'n/a')
- Results have been checked using a pivot table (functions appear in order/no issues apparent).
- hopefully trivial issue / Q RE date formatting - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)

ta,

---

self-checks

[image: pivot with weeknum(date,2) as row label]

*(pivot table omits data that does not exist, needless to say..)*